# StrongSwan - Windows 7 0 IPSec IKEv2 connection problems

Tags: windows-7, linux, ipsec, linux-networking

I am trying to configure a roadwarrior scenario between a linux box with StrongSwan and a Windows Box with Agile VPN. I successfully configured my StrongSwan and my Windows box to connect. The Windows box also gets an IP from the Virtual IP pool and the SA is visible on the StrongSwan server. The "only" issue is, that I cannot ping through the tunnel. Not even directly between the gateway and the rw. On the Windows box I see the additional network device in ipconfig and route, but on the linux machine i cannot see anything.

My ipsec.conf:

> config setup
>          nat_traversal=yes
>          plutostart=no
>
> conn %default
>       keyexchange=ikev2
>       ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
>       esp=aes256-sha1!
>       dpdaction=clear
>       dpddelay=300s
>       rekey=no
>
> conn win7
>       # left=%any
>       left=%defaultroute
>       leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
>       # leftsubnet=10.6.0.0/24
>       leftauth=pubkey
>       leftcert=ipsec.crt
>       leftid=@XXXXX
>       right=%any
>       rightsourceip=10.6.4.0/24
>       rightauth=eap-mschapv2
>       rightsendcert=never
>       eap_identity=%any
>       auto=add
>       pfs=no